# how can i build a plot where placeholder drawings are filled with data from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, shiny

I am fairly new to R/Shiny and want to build something similar to this:
[image]

This is supposed to be a room plan for equipments, but where the locations of the equipments can constantly change. So the rectangles should always be there in the same number and the same position, but the texts that are in the rectangles should be variable. For this I have a dataframe, in which the position description and the equipment name are in it:

```
 ELSE_NR          LAST_EVENT        LOCATION_ID              KUERZEL_HANDLER
 24 BP153800 2023-07-05 09:09:17  be2_ba4_10_tester          MT 338
 13 BP150200                <NA>  be2_ba4_11_tester          MT 302
 17 BP152200                <NA>  be2_ba4_12_tester          MT 322
 29 BP154600                <NA>  be2_ba4_13_tester          MT 346
 50 BP181200 2023-06-23 11:53:41  be2_ba4_14_tester          RC 412
 4  BP124900                <NA>  be2_ba4_19_tester           MT 49
 25 BP153900 2023-06-23 18:39:12  be2_ba4_20_tester          MT 339
 32 BP155100                <NA>  be2_ba4_21_tester          MT 351
 30 BP154800                <NA>  be2_ba4_22_tester          MT 348
 33 BP155200                <NA>  be2_ba4_23_tester          MT 352
 3  BP124700                <NA>  be2_ba4_24_tester           MT 47
 53 BP181600                <NA>  be2_ba4_25_tester          RC 416
 49 BP181100 2023-07-05 09:09:19  be2_ba4_26_tester          RC 411
 5  BP125000                <NA>  be2_ba4_27_tester           MT 50
 36 BP155600                <NA>  be2_ba4_30_tester          MT 356
 19 BP152500 2023-06-06 12:57:13  be2_ba4_31_tester          MT 325
 16 BP152100 2023-07-05 09:09:14  be2_ba4_32_tester          MT 321
 48 BP181000                <NA>  be2_ba4_33_tester          RC 410
 42 BP180400 2023-07-05 09:09:19  be2_ba4_34_tester          RC 404
 2  BP124400                <NA>  be2_ba4_35_tester           MT 44
 8  BP125300                <NA>  be2_ba4_36_tester           MT 53
 45 BP180700                <NA>  be2_ba4_37_tester          RC 407
 41 BP180300 2023-07-05 09:09:14  be2_ba4_40_tester          RC 403
 22 BP153400 2023-07-05 09:09:19  be2_ba4_41_tester          MT 334
 27 BP154300                <NA>  be2_ba4_42_tester          MT 343
 43 BP180500                <NA>  be2_ba4_43_tester          RC 405
 .
 .
 .
```

The empty black strip in the middle of the image symbolizes the corridor. the rectangles are equipments. Note that the big rectangles aren't important to me, the smaller rectangles are the equipments (338, 302, 322, etc. at the bottom of the image).
The `location_id` column can be seen in the dataframe. I have ordered them and if you hold the column `kuerzel_handler` and the image side by side you can see how the `location_id` builds up the assets in the image from bottom right to top left (left of the black corridor) like MT 338 is 338 in the image, MT 302 is 302, etc. After a certain `location_id`, the equipments are on the right side of the corridor.

this is my server.R file:

```
#source(beCommunicationOverview.R)
#library(tidyverse)
library(gtools)
server <- function(input, output) {
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    d=data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), x2=c(2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6), y1=c(5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1), y2=c(6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,2), t=c('RS','RS','RS','MT','MT','MT','MT','RS','MT','MT','DM','DM','DM','DM','DM'), r=c('RS','RS','RS','MT','MT','MT','MT','RS','MT','MT','DM','DM','DM','DM','DM'))
    ggplot() +
        scale_x_continuous(name="x") +
        scale_y_continuous(name="y") +
        geom_rect(data=d, mapping=aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, ymin=y1, ymax=y2, fill=t), color="black", alpha=0.5) +
        geom_text(data=d, aes(x=x1+(x2-x1)/2, y=y1+(y2-y1)/2, label=r), size=4) +
        theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
              axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
              axis.title.x=element_blank(),
              axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="bottom",
              panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
              panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),plot.background=element_blank())
}, res = 96)

output$info <- renderPrint({
    eqpCoordsDF=data.frame(getEquipmentCoords())
    secsEventsDF=getSECSEvents()
    #getEquipmentCoords()
    CoordsDF <- data.frame(eqpCoordsDF[c(2,5,7)])
    #print(s)
    #print(result)
    jointdataset <- merge(secsEventsDF, CoordsDF, by.x = 'ELSE_NR', by.y = 'ELSE_NR',all = TRUE)
    finalDF <- jointdataset[mixedorder(as.character(jointdataset$'LOCATION_ID')),]
    #df2 <- jointdataset[order(jointdataset$'LOCATION_ID'),]
    print(finalDF)
})
}
```

in `output$plot` I just tried to draw some rectangles and it worked, but I don't know how I could link the rectangles and coordinates with the dataframe.

The important part comes now. In `output$info` I call two functions that get me some informations from the database such as the locations and equipment names. After that I merge them and order them so I get the dataframe shown here at the end.

Now we come to my question:

How can I draw these rectangles with the equipment names (`kuerzel_handler`) in it?
Should I add the columns x1, x2, y1, y2 to the dataframe for each row (and if so how can I do it?) Or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: I would make a static lookup table that holds the x1/x2/y1/y2 coordinates for each location. Take the active data, left join the static lookup table to it, and then plot.

Comment: Depending on your familiarity with CSS, it might be less cumbersome to consider your equipment not as rectangles in a plot but cells of a nested row/column system and have Shiny's fluid layout system handle equal sizing and spacing of, say, seven equipment cells in a row of given height. The principle is to assign a `div(id = equipment_xy, ...)` to each equipment, with a child `textOutput` and an inherited or specific CSS class (`div(id = ..., class = ..., ...)`). Then, specify CSS attributes: https://unleash-shiny.rinterface.com/beautify-css.html .